# SignalR connection to old browser drops if new browser opens

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, signalr

I have application in which I am showing data from sensors using SignalR. It uses ASP.net membership to authenticate the users. It all works fine if I only open one browser window(e.g. Firefox). If I open same website in another browser e.g. Chrome at the same time then signalR connection to firefox browser drops even if the user is different. This is what I am using to broadcast message:

## Hub

```
[Authorize]
public class DataHub:Hub
{
     private readonly RealTimeData _sensor;

    public DataHub() : this(RealTimeData.Instance) { }

    public DataHub(RealTimeData data)
    {
       _sensor = data;
    }   

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
       // _sensor.UserId = Context.ConnectionId; changed to
        _sensor.UserId = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
public class RealTimeData
{
   //User Id
    public String UserId { get; set; }
   private readonly static Lazy<RealTimeData> _instance = new Lazy<RealTimeData>(() => new RealTimeData(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DataHub>().Clients));// Singleton instance
    private IHubConnectionContext Clients;
    private void BroadcastDataOfAllSensors(List<SensorDetails> sensor)
    { 
            //Clients.Client(UserId).updateDashboard(sensor);changed to
              Clients.User(UserId).updateDashboard(sensor);      
    }
}
```

## Application Startup

```
public class StartUp
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var idProvider = new UserIdProvider();
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => idProvider);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

## UserId

```
public class UserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
    {
        var userId = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        return userId.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your entire hub class? I don't know anything about `_sensor`, `UserId`, `sensor`, or where you're calling `Clients.Client(UserId).updateDashboard(sensor)` from. Also, when you say that the connection "drops", does that mean that the `disconnected` event fired on the client?

Comment: I added my code. I also changed some code from using ConncectionId to UserId.

Comment: I reproduced the bug and created an issue for it [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2966)